# Rstudio, R, check package: default options (--no-manual ) set by new R version

Tags: r

Could you please help me on changing the default options for Rcmd.exe?

1. scenario: I installed the latest R, version 3.4.1. When I check package using the "Check Package" button from Rstudio, I saw the following:

   `Rcmd.exe check --no-tests --as-cran --no-manual packageName.tar.gz`

   `using options '--no-tests --no-manual --as-cran'`

I am ok with `--no-tests` and `--as-cran` but not ok with `--no-manual`, since I need to create a manual for the package. This default setting is just counter-productive in my case. For version R 3.2.0, `--no-manual` is not set by default.

2. Help: why does R set options this way? how does it set the default options? How to remove `--no-manual` so it always tries to generate a manual?

Thank you a lot for your help in advance.

3. **Observations**: if you have devtools installed, then it is devtools that sets --no-manual as defult when you check your package. just remove devtools, and after that make sure --no-manual does not appear in Configure Build Tools; then you're all set if you always want a manual since now r cmd is in action when checking package. otherwise, with devtools, you run devtools::check manually by without --no-manual or run r cmd check without --no-manual  manually

Comment: Is it not possible to change it through the project options in RStudio?

Comment: The options as cran and no tests were set by me in project options in Rstudio; however, there seems to be no option "--with-manual" that I can put there; the option "--no-manual" does Not show up in project options. It is in action once I check package. Funny that the R gods made it this way in the new version. We mortals are trying to figure out how to default the default

Comment: I am using the same version of rstudio for both versions of r

Comment: Isn't it rstudio setting those defaults? You can call whatever you want from the command line...

Comment: I am aware of the command line option but prefer the automated way once it is properly set up; as I said the --no-manual option does not show up in any Rstudio options but there is no way for me to force it to generate manual in Rstudio check package button or package building option. It is r cmd that check, build, etc, not Rstudio

Comment: found out a solution: remove R package devtool, i.e., do not use devtools to check package. Done. ...